# UIPageViewController responds to vertical pan when orientation is set to horizontal

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

I've burnt hours on this. I've initialized `UIPageViewController` with `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal`, but for some reason `viewControllerBeforeViewController` is called when user pans vertically.

Also, when this happens, there's no page flipping and `didFinishAnimating:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted` isn't called at all. This means that the page view controller knows this is a vertical movement..

This is the initialization code -

```
- (void)initPageViewController
{
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                                                              navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal 
                                                                            options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Leave only pan recognizers enabled, so buttons positioned inside a page would work.
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        if ([gr class] != [UIPanGestureRecognizer class])
            gr.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had initially stumbled across your question facing the same problem - but I seem to have fixed it for my situation.

Basically, what I had to do was set a delegate to all the gesture recognizers attached to the `UIPageViewController`. So, soon after creating the `UIPageViewController`, I did:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in self.book.gestureRecognizers)
    gr.delegate = self.book;
```

where `book` is my custom `UIPageViewController` (I had essentially set itself as the delegate). Finally, add this method to your `UIPageViewController` to restrict any vertical panning (or use the commented out line instead to restrict horizontal panning).

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];

        return fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y);
//      return fabs(translation.y) > fabs(translation.x);
    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```

I was hinted towards this thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118827/1089059) - just make sure you filter out the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s only.

Comment: tried this but for me the recognizer gets stuck after the first event and always returns the same translation value afterwards...

Comment: I have posted another possible solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533240/uipageviewcontroller-gesture-is-calling-viewcontrollerafter-but-doesnt-animate, you may check out that as well.

Comment: Cheers Ahmed, that solved it. Although I don't understand why isn't this done by the page view controller.

Comment: This solution caused a bounds exception when paging on the last page. That problem was solved at the this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561336/in-ios6-setting-your-pageviewcontrollers-gesturerecognizers-delegate-to-a-view) post, helped me as well, so it needs to be an integral part of this solution.